# BouncyCastle: Non existend attachment shown in encrypted Email

Tags: email, encryption, outlook, attachment, bouncycastle

I encountered a strange behaviour using BouncyCastle.

A email without any attachment is encrypted in BouncyCastle and send through JavaMail.
Looking at it in Outlook, an attachment is shown. In fact there is no given opening the encrypted mail.

Encrypting the email just with Outlook, there is no such phantom-attachment.

Any idea why BC is doing this?
Is there any way to avoid it?

Thank you very much!

Nick

Comment: What is the attachment name? Or do you mean Outlook shows the paperclip icon next to the message but lists no attachments.

Comment: Secound one. The paperclip is shown, but there is no attachment within.

Comment: Outlook normally sets a special named property (SmartNoAttach - you should be able to see it in OutlookSpy if you click the IMessage property), why Outlook does not set that property on a message generated by BC, I do not know. Try to post the complete MIME source of the generated message.

Comment: Ok, I was able to manage the property using the OutlookSpy. Great tool! Thank you very much! Now there is one missing part. So what is the best way to set a MAPI-property within JavaMail? I found JTNEF and the Apache POI project. JTNEF is hardly documented and POI not just a readonly solution right now. Have you got a good hint for me? Btw: If you post your comment as an answer, I would like to give you an "answered" flag :)

Comment: Are you creating the message directly in Outlook? Or send it through SMTP and Outlook retrieves it using POP3 or IMAP4?